# Expo React Native SSR

Tags: react-native, express, expo, seo, server-side-rendering

I have a project built on Expo and react-native-web for Android, IOS and Web as well.
I am using Expo router for navigation and @shopify/restyle for styling.
I want to implement SEO or SSR to this web application.

I have tried Solito but couldn't get it to work also tried the expo next js documentation to implement the next js into expo web but I am confused on the navigation part because next js and expo router both performs file based routing.
Is there any way I can create a separate express app for SSR?
How do I generate SEO-friendly markup for a single-page web app?

Answer (score 1):

Expo Router uses file based routing when your app runs on React Native. It mirrors NextJS file based routing conventions.

NextJS uses file based routing when your app runs on web.

Solito unifies Expo and NextJS navigation (a unified Link component). You need Solito for this to work.

So use Expo + NextJS + Solito

It’s slighlty different from using vanilla Expo Web:

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-nextjs/#limitations-or-differences-compared-to-the-default-expo-for-web

NextJS has its own web server (based on Express). If you use NextJS then you don’t need a separate Express server.

NextJS will generate SEO friendly markup for you when you SSR with it.